# ESP-01S Relay V1.0 connection with Arduino

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am new to Arduino

Let me ask you about IOT(internet of things).

I want to connect ESP-01S Relay v1.0

Where does the NC port goes on Arduino? Is it TX or RX?

Also, where does the NO goes on Arduino? Is it TX or RX?

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit and improve your question:  See [How to ask](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2523/19409)

Answer (score 2):

The 2 connections you refer to (NC and NO) are connections to the relay switch.

- **NO** stands for *normally open*
- **NC** stands for *normally closed*
- **C** or **COM** stands for *common*

[image: basic relay diagram]

When the relay is unenergised, the common is connected to the NC terminal. When power is applied to the relay, the coil energises and switches, so now common is connected to the NO terminal.

From my reading of the usage document located on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/IOT-MCU/ESP-01S-Relay-v1.0), you are supposed to program the ESP module before plugging it into the relay board. There are no terminals broken out for you to connect to the Tx and Rx on the relay board.

However, the following board from [AUS-eParts](http://auseparts.com.au/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=377) has a header to connect a 3V TTL cable. This can be used to program the ESP module.

[image: Relay board with TTL header]

Comment: the RX/TX header is good, but you need io 0 LOW at boot to put the esp8266 into flashing mode

Answer (score 0):

Common, Normally Connected and Normally Open are terminals switched by the relay. There you connect what should be switched. Common is input and the two other terminals are connected, one if the coil is powered and the other when the coils is without power. The relay is controlled by the esp-01. No Arduino should be connected to this.

Disconnect the esp-01 from the relay board and use an 3.3 V USB-to-TTL Serial adapter [to program the esp-01 with Arduino IDE](https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap01%20-%20ESP8266.html)

Add Over The Air support to your esp8266 sketch with ArduinoOTA library and then you can upload new versions of your sketch over WiFi. To debug the sketch with `print` use Telnet server or my [TelnetStream library](https://github.com/jandrassy/TelnetStream).

Comment: How to communicate with server? I have no RX or TX port

Comment: what server? with network server you should communicate over WiFi

Comment: I mean how i can access server via wifi? This module doesnt have RX and TX pins. Only NC, COM and NO

Comment: as I can see on the picture in the question, there is an esp-01 connected to the 2x3 header

Comment: esp is connected but this relay what i got, got no RX and TX pins

Comment: the esp-01 has RX TX. you must disconnect it from the relay to flash a sketch to it